# Is fractional Laplacian a mean zero transform?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $f$ be a nice smooth function $[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ with $f(0)=f(1)$, $f'(0)=f'(1)$. Then it is straightforward that its Laplacian (=second derivative) is a mean-zero function, i.e.,
$$
\int_0^1 f''(x) dx=0.
$$

Now let $L_\alpha:=(-\Delta)^{\alpha/2}$ be the fractional Laplacian (in 1 dimension). Is it true that
$$
\int_0^1 L_\alpha f(x) dx=0
$$ 
for all $\alpha\in (0,2)$?

Comment: I think you should specify which Laplacian you mean - boundary conditions. And which type of [fractional derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus#Fractional_derivatives).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Laplacian with periodic conditions would give
$$
      (-\Delta)^{\alpha/2}f = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}|2\pi n|^{\alpha}\hat{f}(n)e^{2\pi inx}.
$$
The above appears to be mean-free because the coefficient of $e^{i0x}$ is $0$.